# Do Sera Guardians count towards the 'What Is that Thing?' challenge?

Tags: borderlands

I'm on my 2nd playthrough of Borderlands and I have only 30 guardian kills towards the 'What is that Thing?' guardian kill [challenge](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Challenge).

I've noticed that at the end portion of the game, you kill a bunch of those [Sera Guardians](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sera_Guardian), but they don't bump your guardian kill count for the challenge.

According to the wiki:

> A Sera Guardian is an aerial form of Guardian, pink and greyish-green
>   in colour, that levitates high in the air during combat.

I understand that killing Boz Scaggs doesn't count against your Skag kill count, but these things are Guardians.

So, why don't they count?

Comment: This might be asking for developer intent. Are you asking if there's a bug, or are you asking why the developers chose not to have those kills count?

Comment: I was curious to see if anyone else had come across this; my google-fu found nothing, as if it were just me. If it's a bug (or developer intent), why can't I find any evidence of anyone else with the same issue?

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you're asking "*Do* the Sera Guardians count towards...", not "why". I'm suggesting this because questions asking about developer intent get closed.

Comment: I have a feeling it's because they're different entities as far as the game logic is concerned. As to whether that's an oversight by the developers or intentional, that's not something we can answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure. However, if you still wish to gain the accomplishment, then a great place to go is the Eridian Promontory, which is close to the end of the game. Interestingly enough, the Guardian kills in this area do not seem to count, yet the achievement does show up after 50 kills. So, this is probably an overlooked glitch by developers.

Comment: I'm confused by "the Guardian kills in this area do not seem to count, yet the achievement does show up after 50 kills". What do you mean by "do not seem to count" if they end up counting?

Comment: @DCShannon - Confusing, yes. But they do say "achievement" not challenge. So maybe an achievement unlocks but the challenge still does not (like the OP asks about)? Of course, assuming there is an achievement for that challenge and terms are not being misused.